# mongoose populate array of object id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to get nested data by using populate (One big schema have many properties, one of the properties is like an array of id's to another schema).
I want to got the nested schema by find it with id's.

First schema -
Sector:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const sectorsSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  img: { type: String, required: true },
  poc: { type: String, required: true },
  PhoneNum: { type: String, required: true },
  EmailPOC: { type: String, required: true },
  subSectors: [
    { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "subSectors" },
  ], //store all objectId of Place as an array
  file_gallery: [
    { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Files" },
  ], //store all objectId of Place as an array
  web_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "MainContent" },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("sectors", sectorsSchema);
```

document example:
[image]

And SubSector:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const subSectorsSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  desc: { type: String, required: true },
  img: { type: String, required: true },
  poc: { type: String, required: true },
  PhoneNum: { type: String, required: true },
  EmailPOC: { type: String, required: true },
  QnA: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "QnA" }], //store all objectId of QnA as an array
  file_gallery: [
    { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Files" },
  ], //store all objectId of Files as an array
  sector_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "sectors" },
  web_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "MainContent" },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("subSectors", subSectorsSchema);
```

document example:
[image]

As you can see the two documents got a connection between them (each sector can have many subSector in it).

I am trying to get the subSector by using the populate method of mongoose.
this is my code, but it is doesn't work...

```
  const subSectorId = req.params.subSectorid;
  const sectorId = req.params.sectorid;
  let sector;
  try {
    sector = await Sectors.findById(sectorId)
      .findOne({ _id: subSectorId })
      .populate("subSectors");
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not delete sector.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!sector) {
    const error = new HttpError("Could not find sector for this id.", 404);
    return next(error);
  }
```

The response I got:
"message": "Could not find sector for this id."

The parameters I send are (you can see in the image that they are belong to the document photos I attach):

```
const subSectorId = 62dd1c9f720d07f2488c65a3
const sectorId = 62dd21a82bf3289ef6f08219
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem by my self :)

```
 sector = await Sectors.findById(sectorId).populate({
   path: "subSectors",
   match: { _id: subSectorId },
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate pipeline instead of populate

```
sector = await Sectors.aggreagate([
{$match:{_id:mongoose.types.ObjectId(sectorId)},
{$lookup:{
from: "subSectors",
  let: { subSectorId: mongoose.types.ObjectId(// replace your subSectorId here) 
},
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$subSectorId "] }
      }
    }
  ],
  as: "subSectors"
 }}
 ]);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).